# How to get the datatype of a column of a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the datatype of a column of a view in SQL Server. Is there an efficient way to do that?

I have to get the Database Name, Schema, View Name all dynamically from one database, look for the view in another database and find the data type of the column in the third database.

E.g.

```
SELECT @db2 = Name FROM db1.schema.databases
SELECT @c = Name FROM db1.schema.columns
SELECT @v = Name FROM db1.schema.views


SELECT @datatype = query to get {datatype} of column {c} from {db2}.{schema}.{v}
```

Here column {c} of `{db2}.{schema}.{v}` can refer another database say {db3}

Please suggest.

Comment: check sp function sp-describe-first-result-set. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you need, but this might help you:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.TestView AS
SELECT * FROM master..spt_values;
GO
```

--This is the view's output

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestView;
GO
```

--Set your variables

```
DECLARE @db2 VARCHAR(100) = 'master';
DECLARE @c  VARCHAR(100) = 'type';
DECLARE @vSchema  VARCHAR(100) = 'dbo';
DECLARE @vName VARCHAR(100) = 'TestView'
```

--The query will display the `DATA_TYPE` and all other columns returned by `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

```
SELECT c.DATA_TYPE
      ,c.* 
FROM master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME=@vName 
  AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA=@vSchema
  AND c.COLUMN_NAME=@c
  AND c.TABLE_CATALOG=@db2; --forgot this in the first post...
```

--Clean-Up

```
GO
DROP VIEW dbo.TestView;
```

It's a bit fuzzy, that the `COLUMNS` view returns tables and views as if they were the same. The advantage: You can use the same approach to check a table's column...

Hint: This `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is just a *built-in* view looking into the corresponding `sys` tables.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS works for me, but I had to create dynamic query because the schema and database name were coming from another database.

Comment: But this did not help finding the data types of the information_schema.columns view columns themselves, therefore I asked [How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1155571/how-do-i-get-something-like-the-information-schema-columns-metadata-view-of-the).

Comment: sp-describe-first-result-set-transact. there is a way to get that info on view or stored proc call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16